# Moving many files in the same bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I've got 200k files in a bucket which I need to move into a sub folder within the same bucket, whats the best approach?

Answer (score 69):

I recently encountered the same problem. I solved it using the command line API.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html

```
aws s3 mv s3://BUCKETNAME/myfolder/photos/ s3://BUCKETNAME/myotherfolder/photos/ --recursive
```

I had a need for the objects to be publicly viewable, so I added the `--acl public-read` option.

Comment: IIRC, you will be charged for each command copy and delete that the mv will make in the background, as AWS do not have a "move" command, aws script will fakes that using the copy and then delete for each file recursively

Comment: @higuita As per my understanding, there is no way out of this. Move/Rename is not provided by AWS.

Comment: This saved my day for moving 700,000 files to another directory!

Comment: Copy/delete is no problem, since delete requests are free. PUT, COPY, POST, or LIST cost $0.005 per 1,000 requests (standard). So e.g. moving 700,000 objects is $3.50 (same as only copying them).

Comment: @martin blank should vote this as Accepted Answer :)

Comment: I've edited this answer for security reasons. Putting `--acl public-read` in the main code body is problematic for people that don't know AWS or its security model and tend to rapidly copy/paste and try code without understanding it (many, many people). It also doesn't answer the question which doesn't mention public ACL so I put that option code at the end with the comment.

Comment: This isn't actually moving into a subfolder of the original folder. It is moving to a different folder within the bucket, at the same level as the original folder. Due to the OP's wording, I'm not sure exactly which the OP meant. But for a subfolder of the original folder, nokatzhere's answer covers that, though be sure to check the important comment below!

Answer (score 40):

Recently was able to do this with one command. Went much faster than individual requests for each file too.

Running a snippet like this:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket-name/ s3://bucket-name/subfolder --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"
```

Use the `--include` flag to selectively pick up the files you want

Comment: You forgot the `--recursive` flag

Comment: A word of warning: This can cause objects to be made in your bucket with a key composed of 'deeply-nested' subfolders, e.g. s3://bucket-name/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/blah.txt.  Circumvent this problem by adding an additional exclude:  $ aws s3 mv s3://bucket-name/ s3://bucket-name/subfolder --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.txt" --exclude "subfolder/*"

Comment: Great comment by @JoshuaT ! The other answer doesn't have this issue since it is moving files to another folder on the same hierarchical level as the source folder. But this one is really moving to a subfolder (like the question asks). Adding --recursive acts on all objects in the folder, but also objects in all subfolders. So it could move one to the subfolder, and then move it again to an extra nested subfolder. And if you have files already in the subfolder they would be moved one level deeper. The extra --exclude in his comment prevents that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'Rename' operation though it would be great if there was.

Instead, you need to loop through each item that you want to rename, perform a copy to a new object and then a delete on the old object.

- http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html
- http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html

Note: for simplistic purposes I'm assuming you don't have versioning enabled on your bucket.

Comment: that sounds very painful! API seems to be optimized for making money, not for being convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and I ended up using `aws s3 mv` along with a bash `for` loop.

I did `aws ls bucket_name` to get all of the files in the bucket. Then I decided which files I wanted to move and added them to `file_names.txt`.

Then I ran the following snippet to move all of the files:

```
for f in $(cat file_names.txt)
do
    aws s3 mv s3://bucket-name/$f s3://bucket-name/subfolder/$f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

if your files are in a folder, you can use **s3cmd** tool

```
s3cmd cp --recursive s3://bucket/folder/ s3://bucket/sub_folder/
```

Ps: I'm assuming you have already installed and configured s3cmd

Answer (score -2):

The below script works perfectly to me without any issues

```
for i in `cat s3folders`
do 
     aws s3 mv s3://Bucket_Name/"$i"/ s3://Another_Bucket_Name/ --recursive
done
```

It also delete the empty folder from source once the files moved to the target.

Comment: How does Another_Bucket_Name meet the "same bucket" requirement? Where does s3folders come from?